# Adding Class one by one , each class adding after one second

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

My target : Adding Class one by one[test0 test1 test2] until 10 , each class adding after one second

```
$('.rating-block').AddClass('test0 test1 test2 ... test10' );
```

My code [ Just trying with this code, No more idea about this code]

```
       for ( var i = 0; i < 11 ; i = i + 1 ) {
             setTimeout(function(){
                $( ".rating-block" ).addClass('test' +i);
                console.log(  i );
            },1000);
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 11 ; i = i + 1 ) {
    (function (j) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $( ".rating-block" ).addClass('test' + j);
            console.log( j );
        }, i * 1000);
    }(i));
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vnyhojvj/).

---

UPDATE: You can reverse it simply:

```
for ( var i = 10; i >= 0 ; i = i - 1 ) {
    (function (j) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $( ".rating-block" ).removeClass('test' + j);
            console.log( j );
        }, (11 - i) * 1000);
    }(i));
}
```

Even you can make these code as functions and make a loop (add from 0 to 10, then remove from 10 to 0 and so on):

```
function addClasses() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < 11 ; i = i + 1 ) {
        (function (j) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $( ".rating-block" ).addClass('test' + j);
                console.log( j );
            }, i * 1000);
        }(i));
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        removeClasses();
    }, 10 * 1000);
}

function removeClasses() {
    for ( var i = 10; i >= 0 ; i = i - 1 ) {
        (function (j) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $( ".rating-block" ).removeClass('test' + j);
                console.log( j );
            }, (11 - i) * 1000);
        }(i));
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        addClasses();
    }, 10 * 1000);
}

addClasses();
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vnyhojvj/2/).

Comment: This will set all classes immediately after 1 second, not one by one per second.

Comment: oh, I see now you use `i` variable, you're right. Your solution also can work.

Comment: Can we reverse (removing class) after 10th class ? @ROX

Comment: @ShibinRagh Yes, it's possible, check the updated answer, and also you can make it a loop...

Answer (score 3):

Better to use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) here:

```
var i = 0
  , interval = null;

interval = setInterval(function(){
    $( ".rating-block" ).addClass('test' +i);
    i++;
    if( i == 11 ) {
        clearInterval( interval );
    }
},1000);
```

Because using `setTimeout` will force you to implement promises functionality or add about 10 callbacks and your code will be ugly.

EDIT:

To reverse you can simply extend code above and add another setInterval

```
if( i == 11 ) {
    clearInterval( interval );
    i = 10;
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        if( i == 0 ) {
            clearInterval( interval );
        }
        $( ".rating-block" ).removeClass('test' +i);
        i--;
    },1000);
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7h7v668e/)

Comment: Can we reverse (removing class) after 10th class ? @antyrat